# Balanced Assignment Problem with updatable cost

Tags: dynamic-programming, linear-programming, assignment-problem

I have a problem that can be reduced to an assignment problem. (this is related to some [cryptography problems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4442871/permuted-hamming-distance))

Which means we have a set $A$ of $n$ agents and an equal size set $T$ of tasks as well as a cost function $c(i,j)$, and one wants to find a bijection $\sigma: A\to T$ that maximizes the satisfaction of the agents :

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} c(i, \sigma(j)).
$$

This is well-known that the Hungarian algorithm can find an optimal solution $C^*$ to the balanced assignment problem in time at worst $O(n⁴)$. (the problem of minimizing and maximizing previous sum are equally hard problems).

Now suppose an agent changes his mind about one task, he better supports one job which means we add $1$ to an element of the cost matrix, let's write $c'$ this new cost matrix. We have the relationship $c' = c + E_{ij}$ for some $1\le i,j\le n$.

**My question:** is there a way to compute the optimal cost $C'^*$ faster than $O(n⁴)$ using $C^*$?

(One may remark that $1 \ge C'^* - C^* \ge 0$.)

Comment: Wikipedia claims the running time of the Hungarian algorithm is $O(n^3)$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem#Balanced_assignment, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm.